# How to get the cell position of QCombobox which is a QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qcombobox

So the below code is part of a bigger project but in general, I have a QTableWidget which is populated from a database. One of the items is a combobox which when the user selects a milestone option from the combobox I want to be able to know which row and column the combo box that was select is in so I can then apply a fixed rate to the value of a cell in the same row. All I need help on is how to track which cell (row, column) the combo box that was selected is in.

Please note im using other tabs that are not shown and is why my code is setup the way it is. I found some other help but am not a very experience python programmer so I got stuck.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin9 -*-
import sys, os , random
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot,SIGNAL,SLOT
import time
import json
import openpyxl
import Lists

class CashflowTab(QtGui.QDialog):
    '''
    Parent for all tab widgets of the REPO GUI
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(CashflowTab, self).__init__()
        if parent != None:
            self.setParent(parent)
        self.initUI()
        self.loadSettings()

    def loadSettings(self):
        '''
        read settings and read db
        '''
        fh = open('settings.json')
        self.settings = json.load(fh)
        fh.close()
        #load db
        dbpath = self.settings['dbpath']
        self.db = Lists.SQLiteHandler(dbpath)
        self.repo = Lists.WCNList('ROSQL')

        try:
            self.db.read(self.repo)
        except:
            pass

class WCNSelectTab(CashflowTab):
    '''
    Window for WCN selection
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(WCNSelectTab, self).__init__(parent)
        if parent != None:
            self.setParent(parent)


    def initUI(self):
        global wbsitem, WCNSelectTab_object, linequerycheck
        linequerycheck = 'False'
        wbsitem = 'null'
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("cleanlooks"))
        gbox = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)

        self.projectlist = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.projectlist.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        #self.projectlist.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.projectlist.setColumnCount(3)
        self.projectlist.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QtCore.QStringList(['WBS','Service','Milestone']))
        self.projectlist.setColumnWidth(0, 100)       
        self.projectlist.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
        self.projectlist.setColumnWidth(2, 150)

        gbox.addWidget(self.projectlist,5,0,3,6)

        self.getAwardBudget()

    def getAwardBudget(self):

        global wbs_details

        wbs_details = []
        wbs_details.append(["123", "Service 1"])
        wbs_details.append(["456", "Service 2"])        
        print wbs_details

        self.projectlist.setRowCount(len(wbs_details))
        for n,item in enumerate(wbs_details):            

            qitem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(item[0])
            self.projectlist.setItem(n, 0, qitem)
            qitem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(item[1])
            self.projectlist.setItem(n, 1, qitem)
            milestone_options = ["Award","Mobilization","Survey"]
            milestonecombo = QtGui.QComboBox()
            for t in milestone_options:
                milestonecombo.addItem(t)
            milestonecombo.setFixedWidth(150)
            self.projectlist.setCellWidget(n, 2, milestonecombo)


class RepoGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    '''
    Main Widget for REPO helper
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super(RepoGUI, self).__init__()
        #self.mode = mode
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        global approval, approval_names, username, approval_names
        self.tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.tabs.setAutoFillBackground(1)

        fh = open('settings.json')
        settings = json.load(fh)
        fh.close()

        if settings['WCNsubmit'] == 1:
            self.tabs.addTab(WCNSelectTab(), 'WCN Creation') 

        self.setWindowTitle('Work Completion Notification')  
        self.setGeometry(300, 150, 1400, 800)
        self.setStyleSheet('font-size: %ipt' %settings['fontsize'])   

        self.show()    

def main(): 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = RepoGUI()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use `indexAt()` since the position of the `QComboBox` is relative to the `viewport()`, but to obtain the `QComboBox` that was selected we use `sender()`.

```
    for n,item in enumerate(wbs_details):            

        qitem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(item[0])
        self.projectlist.setItem(n, 0, qitem)
        qitem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(item[1])
        self.projectlist.setItem(n, 1, qitem)
        milestone_options = ["Award","Mobilization","Survey"]
        milestonecombo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        milestonecombo.addItems(milestone_options)
        milestonecombo.setFixedWidth(150)
        milestonecombo.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onCurrentIndexChanged)
        self.projectlist.setCellWidget(n, 2, milestonecombo)

def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, text):
    combobox = self.sender()
    ix = self.projectlist.indexAt(combobox.pos())
    print(ix.row(), ix.column(), text)
```

Another possible solution is to use the property:

```
    for n,item in enumerate(wbs_details):            

        qitem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(item[0])
        self.projectlist.setItem(n, 0, qitem)
        qitem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(item[1])
        self.projectlist.setItem(n, 1, qitem)
        milestone_options = ["Award","Mobilization","Survey"]
        milestonecombo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        milestonecombo.addItems(milestone_options)
        milestonecombo.setFixedWidth(150)
        milestonecombo.setProperty("row", n)
        milestonecombo.setProperty("column", 1)
        milestonecombo.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onCurrentIndexChanged)
        self.projectlist.setCellWidget(n, 2, milestonecombo)

def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, text):
    combobox = self.sender()
    r = combobox.property("row").toPyObject()
    c = combobox.property("column").toPyObject()
    print(r, c, text)
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, ill take a look here today and see if I can get your example working.

Comment: Eyllanesc, thanks so much. I was beating my head into a wall with this as I tried so many things I found on here and was close but your solution is perfect! I usually find code snippets online and go from there so I don't have a very strong understanding of the very detailed functions of python, just a general knowledge of programming.

Comment: @JeremyWestfall 
I recommend you invest more time in reading and understanding the documentation. patch code will work at the beginning, but then it will be very difficult, I would say impossible, to maintain. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour].